# Mathematica keyboard problem: Typing integral limits

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I'm using a Czech keyboard and I'm trying to figure out how to put the upper limit into integral. Normally one would use <kbd>Esc</kbd> `int` <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> to put in the lower limit and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> to put in the upper limit.
Problem is that on the Czech keyboard the percentage is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> key. So to use put in the upper limit I thought I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> but this doesn't work.

**Is there any way to get around that?**

I know about the [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) function but I want my notebooks to be more readable.

Comment: Have you considered using Esc + dintt + Esc?

Comment: Try `CTRL-SHIFT-<comma>-5` and then putting in the various parts into the placeholders. Notice, also, that `CTRL-SHIFT-<minus>-5` will put the limit placeholders just in front of the main placeholder, instead of above and below it.

Comment: I am using the program "Clavier+" to define my keys.

Comment: Thank you all for the solutions.

Comment: [This documentation](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/mathematical-typesetting/) may help, including "Clicking a palette button" and "Convert existing cells to `TraditionalForm`", not covered in the other comments. You could formally answer your own question to document the solutions that actually work.